# How do I use jqgrid free with ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, free-jqgrid

I want to display a grid of data. I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

I could just write some less than great code to loop through my view model and create a javascript string, something like:

```
var data = "[";
@foreach (var item in Model.items} {
   <text>"{ Name: " + item.Name + "},";</text>
}
data += "]";
// outputs several lines of javascript to build up a data object that I can feed into jqgrid
```

However to avoid this I figure, why not just put the data into an ajax method? I have seen other questions floating around suggesting that you can use `data: <ajax command of some sort>` but the [documentation](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) has absolutely nothing on how to do this.

I am wondering if it's possible, and if so, what format should the return json be in in order to be used by the jqgrid free?

Answer (score 0):

To load data with ajax you can use option `url`, and to add/edit/delete data you can use option `editurl`.

Example:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: '/your-url',
    editurl: '/your-edit-url'
    ...
}
```

---

Note:
[free-jqgrid](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/) is based on [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). free-jqGrid is not fully documented but you can find help in older documentation of jqGrid.

For most of the options you will find documentation in:

- [wiki of tirand](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs)
- [demos from trirand](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)
- [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jqgrid)